# Should I declare contract every time in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ethers.js

I created my first React - Solidity application. It uses ethers library and I can successfully

1. Check and connect to Metamask
2. Get Provider + Signer
3. Get contract using my contract address + ABI and either the provider or signer.

then execute functions in my contract. My understanding is that provider = readOnly and signer = write, so I'm wondering whether you should declare a new contract object/instance every time before you call functions? Or do you reuse it and keep it in a state?

Answer (score 1):

The best is to create one every time using let so the user dont hold the contract object all the time and yes the provider for read and signer for write and pay

Answer (score 1):

I really like to use this hook:

```
import { Contract } from '@ethersproject/contracts'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { CONTRACT_ADDRESS } from '../constants'
import { IContract, Artifact } from '../contract'
import { useProvider } from '../hooks'

export const useContract = () => {
  const [contract, setContract] = useState<IContract>()
  const provider = useProvider()

  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async function () {
      const _contract = new Contract(
        CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        Artifact.abi,
        provider?.getSigner() || ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby')
      ) as IContract
      setContract(_contract)
    })()
  }, [provider])

  return contract
}
```

The `useProvider` hook is a part of the web3-react library which is an industry standard, developed by the tech lead of Uniswap.